# Can Firebase Billing be minimized through Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

Hi everyone I would like to ask some questions for Firebase Billing described in its official billing [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing).

The guide clearly points out that downloaded data from the database to each connected client app incur billing. I was wondering if this can be lessened by using Google Cloud Functions' [HTTP Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), specially when traversing tons of child nodes for statistical computations and relational database-like comparisons?

I am planning to simulate simple relational database queries to parse Firebase's json data by putting all computation and comparison-heavy methods, like, find all `charNames with ener > 100`; `sum of hp of all messages`; find `all charNames in serverName='bahr'`; etc in the Google Cloud functions. This will be used for a web-based admin dashboard for viewing and organizing data (previously collected thru an android ODK-like app, also connected to the same Firebase database).

I wonder if this will lessen Firebase's billed download (data downloaded, protocol overhead, SSL encryption overheard, and connections), since the main client that requests for firebase data (at the root level) is the server where Google Cloud Functions is hosted?

Further more, can any of the REST API helper libraries mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) make a good substitute for Google Cloud Functions, and lessen Firebase billing too?

Can you also provide other ways to lessen the billing aside from the mentioned samples on the link? Thanks.

I have a firebase json structure like:

[image]